# Javascript cascading dropdown loading problem

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to web programming and I am trying to make a cascading drop down menu using html and js. I have found examples, such as the one I am modifying, that seem to work for me.  The input will eventually be a separate JSON file.

I have isolated the issue and created the following capture.html:

```
<head>
    <script src="dropdn.js"></script>

</head>
    <select id="menu1">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            </select>     
    <br>      
    <select id="menu2">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            </select>      
    <br>  
    <select id="menu3">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            </select>
```

with a js file:

```
var menudata = {
    "CX": {
        "C1": {
            "SX": {
                "G1": []
            }
        },
        "C2": {
            "C2a": {
                "G2": []
            }
        },
        "CL": {
            "L1": {
                "AB": [],
                "OP": []
            },
            "L2": {
                "HP": [],
                "OP": []
            },
            "L3": {
                "OP": [],
                "SI": []
            }
        },
        "PL": {
            "CM": {
                "EI": [],
                "SI": []
            },
            "LG": {
                "AB": [],
                "OP": []
            },
            "PC": {
                "P1": [],
                "PC": []
            }
        },      
    }
}

window.onload = function () {

    //Get html elements
    var menu1 = document.getElementById("menu1");
    var menu2 = document.getElementById("menu2");   
    var menu3 = document.getElementById("menu3");

    //Load menus
    for (var location in menudata) {
        menu1.options[menu1.options.length] = new Option(location, location);
    }

    //menu1 Changed
    menu1.onchange = function () {       
        menu2.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        menu3.length = 1; // remove all options bar first    
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
            return;      
        for (var facility in menudata[this.value]) {
            menu2.options[menu2.options.length] = new Option(facility, facility);
        }
    }   
    //menu2 Changed
    menu2.onchange = function () {       
        menu3.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
            return;
        for (var area in menudata[menu1.value][this.value]) {
            menu3.options[menu3.options.length] = new Option(area, area);
         }
    }   
}
```

When I run capture, everything seems to work fine; however, if I try to load the capture.html into an index.html, all my data is lost (blank dropdowns).  This is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="dropdn.js"></script>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("capture.html");
  });
});    
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Test load of capture.html</h1>
</br>
<div id="div1"><button>Load Capture.html</button></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?  I have gotten as far as something to do with window loading, but I'm not getting very far. I'm guessing I'm missing a fundamental concept here.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dropdn.js script relies on window.onload(). 
When index.html gets its window.onload triggered, the elements you want to populate do not exist yet, so the script fails.
When capture.html gets loaded into the div the onload event of index.html does not get triggered again, so the function does not run.

So I would suggest to remove onload from the script and just make it a function. Then you can use the callback of `JQuery.load()` to actually trigger the function.

So to keep it as simple as possible, I would suggest trying the following:

**1)** Remove the script and head tag from capture.html so that it only contains the `<select>` tags and the `<option>`s.

**2)** Change dropdn.js to be something like:

```
var populate_dropdowns = function() {
    //...your dropdown code...
}
```

instead of `window.onload = function() { ...your dropdown code... }`

**3)** Move your script tags from inside the `<head>` in index.html to the bottom of the `<body>` tag and add the dropdn.js script there as well:

```
    <div id="div1"><button>Load Capture.html</button></div>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dropdn.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){   
         //... inline code...
      }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**4)** Use the callback of JQuery.load() to trigger your function so that you are sure that the div contains your sections and options before you try changing them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("capture.html", function() {
      populate_dropdowns();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much - that solved my problem - excellent explanation

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the script **dropdn.js** in the **index.html**, because this .js expect  **capture.html**

is ready for use getElementById